# PROC Lifereg - Holding one parameter fixed

Tags: sas

In the LIFEREG procedure, you can specify a generalized gamma distribution using the `dist = gamma` option, which generates an estimate based on the three parameter generalized gamma distribution. SAS states that the standard two parameter gamma distribution isn't available, but it would be if one could fix the Shape parameter to be equal to 1, per http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_gamma_distribution.

Is it possible in LIFEREG to fix a value of a particular parameter, or is there a setup in something like NLMIXED that might work. For reference, the full code I'd be using looks like so:

```
proc lifereg data=work.data;
    model t*event(0) = X  / D= Gamma;   
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a MLE for the 2-parameter gamma distribution in a data step. Snippet:

```
s = log(meanvar) - meanlogvar;
k = (3 - s + sqrt( (s - 3)**2 + 24 * s )) / (12 * s);

do j=1 to &iterations until( abs(k - ki) < &condition );
  ki = k;
  k = ki - ( (log(ki) - digamma(ki) - s) / ((1/ki) - trigamma(ki)) );
end;
theta = meanvar / k;
```

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation